# Issue in calling sharepoint service using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, iis-7.5, office365-restapi

Below code is running fine in dev region but giving following errors when code is running on IIS. Purpose of this code is to call share-point user-profile service. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
try
{
    RESTURL="0}/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + username + "'";
    var passWord = new SecureString();

    foreach (var c in _PWD) passWord.AppendChar(c);

    var credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(_USERid, passWord);
    //Creating Handler to allows the client to use credentials and cookie
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential })
    {
        //Getting authentication cookies
        Uri uri = new Uri(webUrl);
        handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credential.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri));

        //Invoking REST API

        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format(RESTURL, webUrl)).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            string jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return jsonData;
        }
    }
}
```

> Message:The remote name could not be resolved: 'login.microsoftonline.com'
>       StackTrace:   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
>          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.DoPost(String url, String contentType, String body, Func`2 webExceptionHandler)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetUserRealm(String login)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetServiceToken(String username, String password, String serviceTarget, String servicePolicy)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, String username, SecureString password, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, Boolean refresh, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure)

Comment: Would seem as simple as it reads, your IIS server cannot resolve login.microsoftonline.com

Comment: How it can be solved??do i need to add settings in web.config file

Comment: Its not your IIS config failing, it cannot look up the name.. DNS on the server isnt being bounced on to external lookups

Comment: any suggestion @BugFinder , how to proceed for this one

Comment: You need to fix the fact your DNS cant lookup external addresses..

Comment: its not been resolved till now.is code change required?

Comment: No.  dns is not a code thing.. really? You dont know what dns is?